# how search for string in linked list of struct to find all occurrence not only first?

Tags: c, string, search, struct, linked-list

how search for string in linked list of struct to find all occurrence not only first?
I already have searched for first occurrence and succeed by this
Can any one help?

```
struct employee{
int code;
char* name[50];
char* phone[20];
char* address[20];
int age;
float salary;

struct employee* next;
struct employee* prev;
};

struct employee* head;
struct employee* tail;

struct employee* find_address (char* name)
 {
    struct employee* temp = head;
    while (temp && strcmp (temp->name, name))
    {
        temp = temp-> next;
    }
return temp;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `find_address()` function can only return a pointer to a single `employee` record, the only way to find all occurrences is to simply continue to call that function until the returned value equals `tail`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function the following way

```
struct employee * find_address ( const struct employee *begin, const char *name )
{
    while ( begin && strcmp( begin->name, name ) != 0 )
    {
        begin = begin-> next;
    }

    return begin;
}
```

In this case you can use the function recursively in a loop until it will return NULL.

Also you could write function `advance` that moves current position in the list. For example

```
struct employee * advance( const struct employee *begin, size_t n )
{
    while ( n-- && begin ) begin = begin->next;

    return begin;
}
```